# Create and add a new control dynamically to a form

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have created a label using the following code:

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pc = new PictureBox(); 

public static System.Windows.Forms.Label la = new Label();

private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Visible = false;
    pictureBox2.Hide();
    Controls.Add(la);
    la.Location = new Point(78, 191);
    la.Size = new Size(72, 77);
    la.Image = _2WaySMSGatewayApp.Properties.Resources.message;
}
```

I want to be able to create a new label and add it to my form when I click on this label.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click handler:

```
la.Click += new EventHandler(la_Click);
```

Then in the handler:

```
void la_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add new label
}
```

Edit - Explanation from comments. Your code would look like this:

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pc = new PictureBox(); 

public static System.Windows.Forms.Label la = new Label();

private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Visible = false;
    pictureBox2.Hide();
    Controls.Add(la);
    la.Location = new Point(78, 191);
    la.Size = new Size(72, 77);
    la.Image = _2WaySMSGatewayApp.Properties.Resources.message;
    la.Click += new EventHandler(la_Click);
}

void la_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //the new label has been clicked
}
```

Comment: sorry @keyboardP.. i did not understand your code! :( .. will you elaborate a bit? please

Comment: Are you trying to make that new label (`la`) clickable? If so, like the way you added `Location, Size and Image` properties to it, you can add `events`. I've added the `Click` event for the label and linked it to the handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static System.Windows.Forms.Label la = new Label();
```

You've made the label static, there is only one of them.  Adding the *same* label to the Controls collection has no effect.  You need to create a new Label control:

```
private int labelCount;

private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var la = new Label();
    la.Size = new Size(72, 77);
    la.Location = new Point(78, 191 + labelCount * (la.Height + 10));
    la.Image = _2WaySMSGatewayApp.Properties.Resources.message;
    la.Text = "Make it visible";
    labelCount++;
    la.Name = "label" + labelCount.ToString();
    la.Click += new EventHandler(la_Click);
    Controls.Add(la);
}

void la_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var la = (Label)sender;
    // You could use the Name property
    //...
}
```

The intention of this code is hard to guess, I just wrote something that had visible side-effects.

Comment: i`m a beginner.. your code might be very good.. but it`s very difficult for me to understand thou! thankyou anyways.! :)

Comment: i took my time understanding this code but great!.. this code is very well written.. :) thank you..